# what does require('../..') mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reload

I'm trying to integrate some feature to hot reload my client's browser when I update the .jade files using express.

So I've tried multiple ways which claim to be compatible with expressjs, but, as soon as I include them in my app.js, it doesn't work...

For example [reload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reload).

In the documentation, they refer to place

```
var reload = require('../../reload')
```

In **app.js.** And I do so, but I always get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../../reload'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Why is that?

[Reloadify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reloadify) also say to place

```
var reloadify = require('../')(__dirname + '/views');
```

And I end up getting same kind of error.

Comment: try just with var reload = require('reload');

Comment: Yes, +1 to @pegla, but in the reload documentation, why they have that reference? reload is installed in node_modules and require as any package... Maybe a doc mistake?

Comment: Answering to your question, "../.." means upwards two directories

Comment: `..` refers to the parent directory. So `../..` is the parent of the parent.

Comment: Oh god, ahaha. I know .. mean up one dir, but my question was towards express.

I thought it actually ment something special.

Answer (score 1):

I´am sure that the double points have nothing to say it´s just for style. They mean with ../.. the folder of your project where you install the node modules. This means if your project is in c:/test then you must make

```
npm i reloadify -g
```

at folder c:/test then you will get c:/test/node_modules

when your project file is now at c:/test/index.js
you can write this

```
var reloadify = require('reloadify');
```

The error

```
Error: Cannot find module
```

means only that the script can´t find the module because of wrong path as example or if there can´t be found a file